# Error while calling java webservice to wso2 esb in sequence manner

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

In my project, i will call proxy sequence from java web service but the sequence is getting triggered but after the 2nd sequence it will show error like

rely utils error while building pass through proxy stream.

can any one help me out ?

Comment: What are you exactly trying? can you provide your sample code segment and error stack?

Answer (score 0):

Usually that error comes when ESB can't find a matching Message builder for the Content-Type of the message which is passed/returned from the sequence. So you can do the below to get rid of the issue,

Find the Content Type of the message comes from the 2nd sequence.
Enable the matching Message builder for that Content type from the ESB_HOME/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml
Restart ESB

ex: If the message content type is text/xml, then enable below Message builder and restart ESB.

```
<messageBuilder contentType="text/xml"
                       class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
```

Comment: We cannot say this is the reason without looking any logs. If there is no matching builder, it will use the default soap builder to build the message.